# One little problem when exporting a file to SDCARD

Tags: android, file-io

I'm facing a problem: I have a stored data on /data/data/files and o have a menu button "export", when i tap on it the file is well exported in the SDCARD but with 0 as size (no data inside the file).
export.class code:

```
public Export(Context context,String nom) {
        this.context = context;
        this.nom=nom;
       }

    public void transfer(){
        try {
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        Log.d("Carburant", "Sdcard can read/write !!" ); 
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Carburant/");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "settings.dat");
        //FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        copyfile(nom,file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // We can only read the media
        Log.d("Carburant", "Sdcard only read !!" ); 
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
        //  to know is we can neither read nor write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("CARBURANT", e.getMessage());
    }

}

    private void copyfile(String srFile, String dtFile){
        try{
            File f1 = new File(srFile);
            File f2 = new File(dtFile);
          InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
          OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
          }
          in.close();
          out.close();
          Toast.makeText(context, "Export effectué", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            Toast.makeText(context, "File Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String x=ex.getMessage();
            Log.d("Carburant", x);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Echec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
        }
      }

    }
```

Code where to write to the file:

```
if (data != "" ) {
              SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
           String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
           String fileDir = ""+ preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
           myIO.WriteSettings(context,fileDir+fileName, data);
           data = "";
```

WriteSettings method:

```
public static void WriteSettings(Context context, String nom, String data) {
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

        try {
            fOut = context.openFileOutput(nom, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            osw.write(data);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
                    fOut.close();
```

Menu export button:

```
case R.id.export:
    String mainDirPath = this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "settings.dat";
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = this.openFileOutput("settings.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Export myExport = new Export(this,mainDirPath);
        myExport.transfer();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Carburant","File Not found");
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.d("Carburant","ERROR");
    }
            return true;
```

Edited menu export button:

```
case R.id.exporter:
            final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
    fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";

    String mainDirPath = this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + fileDir+fileName;
    Log.d("Carburant",mainDirPath);
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = this.openFileOutput(fileDir+fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Export myExport = new Export(this,mainDirPath);
        myExport.transfer();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Carburant","File Not found");
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.d("Carburant","ERROR");
    }
            return true;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Menu export button code above you are doing this...

```
case R.id.export:
    String mainDirPath = this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "settings.dat";
```

This means mainDirPath will be something like...

```
/data/data/<package name>/files/settings.dat
```

The problem is when you write to the file...

```
String fileDir = ""+ preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
myIO.WriteSettings(context,fileDir+fileName, data);
```

This means that when you create mainDirPath it should be something like...

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String mainDirPath = this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + preferences.getString("login", "") + "." + preferences.getString("marque", "") + "." + "settings.dat";
```

The confusion is this line...

```
fos = this.openFileOutput("settings.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

...which creates an empty file called...

```
/data/data/<package name>/files/settings.dat
```

That file is the one you are copying instead of the one called `login.marque.settings.dat`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: you have completely reason, and i noticed this problem just before you answer me . just look what i did(1st post edited)! I have however one other problem, when i exit the app, all datas are gone(deleted) and i have login.marque.settings.data has size 0! i tried to backup the file in the SDCARD just before exit the app and it gives a file with 0 size!

Comment: i noticed also that after rebooting the app and trying to access to the datas ListView, i have a no datas to display, nothing, no even "no datas to display" configured in the code. Strange , no ?

Answer (score 2):

maybe have a look at this line "while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)"

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len = in.read(buffer);
while (len != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    len = in.read(buffer);
}
```

Comment: @Dasiths: any suggestion ? Thank you.

Comment: @Dasiths: i maked this, but always i have 0 as size. I think that the problem comes from the file in /data/data.... ! But how ? If it has 0 as size=> no contents=> no data readed.:\

Comment: I don't think the test for len > 0 would cause this... the -1 vs 0 distinction for InputStream.read is more relevant for interactive streams, where 'no data now' is different from 'there will be no more data'. With a file-backed input-stream, a 0 byte read would only happen at the end of file, or with an empty source file. Of course, testing for -1 is better style.

Comment: @andrinienn since we now know what the problem is, write a seperate function to read the contents of the file and debug that. I'm not sure but is the byte array size enough to hold your file contents?

Comment: @Dasiths: i have a function that reads the content of the file(line per line) to display it in a Listview.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest single-stepping through this in the debugger, and seeing what happens inside the copyfile method. Does the src file 'nom' exist, with non-zero size?

Best wishes,

Phil Lello

Comment: @Pḧil Lello: Also, the thing that mekes me crazy,i checked right now the file in the /data/data.... with DDMS, and find that it has 0 as size! Why it has 0? no doubt that it's storing data, it has content on it, but why 0! i reboot the application and the data are still here . what could be the problem? Thanks .

Comment: Without single-stepping to see where the copy is failing, it's difficult to say, but I suspect paths are getting messed up somewhere, and you're not copying the file you think you are.

Comment: @Phil Lello: You have absoluetly reason, there is something "strange" on the paths! i really feel that the main problem comes from there :\

Comment: @androniennn: Are you using flush() and/or close() on the source file before you try to read/export it? If you are using BufferedWriter (for example) the file will exist but data isn't 'flushed' (written) to the file until you call flush(). This will be done automatically though if you use close() on the file object before attempting copy.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Yes, when adding data to the file, i have flush(). But as you see above, i think that i don't have to use flush in the copyfile function.

Comment: @androniennn: OK, so it seems the source file is 0 bytes. Show the code where you write to that file and also show the code which creates your Export object.

Comment: I think you need to add Context.getFilesDir() as a prefix to 'nom' (if you're doing it outside copyfile), or open the input file with Context.openInputStream inside copyfile.

Comment: @Phil Lello: i really don't understand your idea :\ ! String mainDirPath = this.getFilesDir(nom); ?

Comment: Ah good, I see MisterSquonk seems to have solved this. I do suggest writing a utility function to build the full path to the settings.dat file, and just using that function when you need the filename - I think building the filename in-place each time gets confusing (confused me!), and could be a maintenance headache.